# How not render some items of an office-ui DetailsList

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric

I have a component with a DetailsList in it. This component receives the items to render from its parent, which is responsible for filtering. Everything is great, except that I also track selection which is cleared if the filtering does not contain the selected items, cause the DetailsList gets new set of items. I changed my filtering method to only give some extra property to the items which I would not like to render and I would like to specify to DetailsList which items to render.
I tried using the `onRenderRow` prop by defining it the following way:

```js
const onRenderRow = (props: IDetailsRowProps) => 
  (props.item.shouldBeRendered) ?
            <DetailsRow {...props} /> : null;
```

The problem with this is, that empty rows are rendered, instead of being skipped totally. Maybe not null should be returned in case of the items that I don't wish to render.
I could not find another prop in the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/detailslist) that could help me out with this.

Comment: Did You try instead of using if else statement, just use if with binary and operator like `(props.item.shouldBeRendered) && <DetailsRow {...props} />`

Comment: @octobus, thanks for the idea. I tried it out, but the effect is the same, where item.shouldBeRendered is false, an empty row is rendered.

Comment: ok, then I think you should make a separate function that takes your `itemList` as an argument and than use `filter` method for filtering your list and return your filtered list.